# .hover(...) and on.("hover"...) behaving differently

Tags: jquery, hover

Using JQuery I am trying to chain a couple of functions when an element has a hover state.

I would normally use the `.hover` event function, but after reading some tutorials I read that using `.on` is better as you can use one event handler to monitor all bubbling events within a document.

However, I am having problems when I chain two functions together like so:

```
$("element").on( "hover", function() {         
    console.log("one");     
}, function() {         
    console.log("two");     
});
```

I expected the result to be **one two** *(which was the case when using `.hover`)* but instead I get **two two**.

Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong or whether this is expected behaviour and why?

**Reproduced using `.hover(...)`: http://jsfiddle.net/gXSdG/**

**Reproduced using `.on(hover...)`: http://jsfiddle.net/gXSdG/1/**

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`.on()` can only take 1 function, so you have to interrogate the passed `event` to check what the event was. Try this:

```
$("element").on("hover", function(e) {
    if (e.type == "mouseenter") {
        console.log("one");   
    }
    else { // mouseleave
        console.log("two");   
    }
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/gXSdG/3/)

Alternatively you can split the two events which constitute the `hover()` method - `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`:

```js
$("#element").on("mouseenter", function() {
  console.log("one");   
}).on('mouseleave', function() {
  console.log("two");   
});
```

```css
#element {
  background-color: black;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="element"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You've just confused about what was happening in the first place, there is no function chaining in either of your examples. The APIs for `hover` and `on` are different, read them carefully, and here's an overview as it pertains to your problem:

[`hover`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) takes either one or two arguments, both functions. The first is run when the mouse enters, the second when the mouse leaves.

[`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) takes only one callback, and your first function is never used, since it's used for a different parameter, and the second one is used as the callback and called for all hover events, that is, mouse enter *and* mouse leave.

Comment: +1 thank you for the explanation, I am still getting the hang of JQuery and I really should have paid more attention to the documentation.